# Reading coordinates linked/separated with underscore

Tags: coordinates

I have a large dataset on bad signal areas in Germany, where UTM coordinates of points are given in one single column, separated by the characters `_ ,` for instance: 281200_5656877

1. Is there a common name on how to call this kind of coordinate notation?
2. Can I open such file in QGIS or ArcGIS without manually separating this columns (e.g. by left- and  right-string commands)?

[Here a small data sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vrkeTu6KkpeKCCzIKiBr0QeYpCfnZWv_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: 1. Yeah, this is called "stupid", or "impractical", depending on your work environment. 2. I suggest you edit the data using excel before trying to dump it into QGIS. Alternatively you could set `_` as custom denominator.

Comment: *delimiter, not denominator. Sorry.

Comment: Lists in attributes are a violation of relational database best practice, so I'd use "non-standard" or "wasteful" to describe this mechanism. GIS applications use spatial data formats for efficiency; needing to parse delimited text is an inefficient approach, so while it may be possible, it certainly isn't recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Excel, LibreOffice etc. seem to have a 1,048,576 row limit, so that would not be an option here.

However, setting _ as an additional separator to , when importing the file to QGIS does the job. (Didn't even know that two separator can be used at once).

Answer (score 2):

Using a ETL (FME) pulling your sample data:

Extracted your coordinates here substring_x, substring_y

and rebuilt the geometry from the coordinates given.

These can be scaled-up easily for millions of points.

[image]